# How to test my own hand drawn numbers in a neural network

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8BIBpya2k) tutorial on how to make a neural network. Everything works great and I feel like I have a pretty solid understanding on everything I did.

I've seen somewhere that people can draw a number on screen, and then run the model to see if it can guess it correctly. I can't find how to do this (To clarify, I wan't to draw one number in my program and test it, not create a whole dataset and load that in) I believe I need to use numpy (though I'm not sure) and then save that as a variable that is 28x28 pixels, black and white, and then have the model predict what it is.

Is this correct? Could someone help point me in the right direction? My code is the same as the one in the video, but so you don't have to watch it, here it is. I separated the code by cell. Thanks for any help!

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist # 28x28 images of handwritten digits 0-9

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

---

```
val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(val_loss, val_acc)
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(x_train[8], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

---

```
model.save('num.model')
```

---

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('num.model')
```

---

```
print(predictions)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
print(np.argmax(predictions[80]))
```

---

```
plt.imshow(x_test[80])
plt.show
predictions = new_model.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

1. Draw your number in a white sheet, and capture it your phone or PC and save it in your PC.
2. Check what your input dimension is:

```
    import keras.backend as K
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
        first_dim = 0
        second_dim = 1
    else:
        input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
        first_dim = 0
        second_dim = 3
```

3. Then,

   ```
   thresh=90
   gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #frame is the image.
   gray_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (5, 5), 0)
   #adaptive here does better with variable lighting:

   gray_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize = 127, C = 2)

   #gray_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
   #                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize = 127, C = 2)
   ```

So this block will convert your image into grayscale to feed it into the model.

3. Then find the contours in the image and feed it to the model using `model.predict()` or `model.predict_classes()`.

You can check my github on [Odia Handwritten character recognition](https://github.com/ASH1998/Augmentation-of-ODIA-Hand-Written-Dataset). I did something same using video capture.

Comment: This is great, but I saw something somewhere I believe used pyplot that allowed you to draw it on your computer, therefore the image dimensions were the same and you could just draw it and predict it, any idea how to do that?

Comment: okay, here are two great links : [mnist-tf](https://github.com/zoulala/MNIST-Tensorflow-flask) and [mnist-classy](https://github.com/mvmanh/mnist-classification)